# How can I get 'PercentComplete' for WBS and Project in Primavera API 7.0 c#?

Tags: c#, primavera

I need to get 'PercentComplete' value for Project and WBS objects. I can find this value only for 'Activity', buy not for Project and WBS.
[Then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3XgJ.png) I get 'Activity' in code with ActivityFieldType.PercentComplete. And [then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIObY.png) i can get PercentComplete for Activity.
But how I can get 'PercentComplete' value for Project and WBS?
PS I use https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16688_01/api/FieldSummary.html documentation for find values what I need.

Comment: Why not using SummaryCostPercentComplete and SummaryDurationPercentComplete for WBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SummaryCostPercentComplete and SummaryDurationPercentComplete on WBS level.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found attrubute SummaryUnitsPercentComplete for WBS, but I run method in namespace 'JobPortType' SummarizeProject(id) before, and it's get me value in this attribute for first level WBS . BUT it doesnt work for WBS second and other level, it has 0 value, but the same WBS has correct percent in Primavera. Maybe something is required to get value in attribute SummaryUnitsPercentComplete for WBS after first level?

Comment: You should increase the WBS summarization level.